# Mongoose graphLookup

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am Trying to Implement Mongoose GraphlookUp in Node JS. but i am not able to find the example code. below code is Copied from mongoose documentation but its not working.

```
aggregate.graphLookup({ from: 'courses', startWith: '$prerequisite', connectFromField: 'prerequisite', connectToField: 'name', as: 'prerequisites', maxDepth: 3 }) // this will recursively search the 'courses' collection up to 3 prerequisites
```

Here is My Code Can You please help me with exact syntax of using graphlook in mongoose using node js

```
const UserTree = require('./model/usertree')
const trees= await  UserTree.aggregate.graphLookup({ 
                    from: 'user_tree', 
                    startWith: '$userpid', 
                    connectFromField: 'userpid', 
                    connectToField: 'userid', 
                    as: 'prerequisites',
                    maxDepth: 3 })
```

Sample Document

```
  {userid: "MongoDB", userpid: "Databases" },
   {userid: "dbm", userpid: "Databases" },
   {userid: "Databases", userpid: "Programming" },
   {userid: "Languages", userpid: "Programming" },
   {userid: "Programming", userpid: "Books" },
   {userid: "Books", userpid: null }
```

Comment: Please provide some sample documents

Comment: {userid: "MongoDB", userpid: "Databases" },
   {userid: "dbm", userpid: "Databases" },
   {userid: "Databases", userpid: "Programming" },
   {userid: "Languages", userpid: "Programming" },
   {userid: "Programming", userpid: "Books" },
   {userid: "Books", userpid: null }

Comment: Seems to work like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-8uDksOyoAn). Small changes in the syntax.

Comment: Thanks I got a Idea From your Playground . Thank Your Very Munch